# Extendinglinearly independent set of polynomials to get a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following subset of $P_{3}(R)$ (real polynomial functions of degree 
 at most 3):

$Z := \{f_{1}; f_{2}; f_{3}; f_{4}; f_{5}\}$ with

- $f_{1}(x) = 1 + 2x - x^2 + 3x^3$,
- $f_{2}(x) = 2 - x + x^2 + x^3$,
- $f_{3}(x) = 5x - 3x^2 + 5x^3$,
- $f_{4}(x) = 1 - 3x + x^2 - x^3$,
- $f_{5}(x) = 4+3x - 2x^2 +8x^3$.

Prune $Z$ to produce a linearly independent subset 
 $Y$ with $\def\Span{\operatorname{Span}}\Span(Z) = \Span(Y)$. What is the dimension of $\Span(Z)$? Is $p_3$ an 
 element of $\Span(Z)$? (Recall that $p_3(x) = x^3$.) Extend $Y$ to give a basis for 
 $P_3(R)$.

I am stuck on the last part (extending $Y$ to get a basis).

Can anyone please explain what I need to do?

Comment: It depends on what tools you're allowed to use; can you use coordinates with respect to a given basis?

Comment: Supposing you've found a linearly independent set $Y$ with less than $\dim(P_3(\Bbb R))=4$ elements, take any generating set (the four monomials will do nicely), and try to add each of those in turn to $Y$ (the set must remain linearly independent). This should always work.

Comment: It doesn't actually say what I can use, it just asks me to extend Y to give a basis. I'm just not really sure what extending it means and what the basis should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

Using the isomorphism $\;P_3(\Bbb R)\cong \Bbb R^4\;$ , denote each one of your polynomials as a $\;4-$ real vector, for instance:

$$1+2x-x^2\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}\;1\\\;2\\\!\!-1\\\;0\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;5x-3x^2+5x^3\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}\;0\\\;5\\\!\!-3\\\;5\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;etc.$$

Now form the usual matrix with the above vectors as rows (or columns, as you prefer), reduce it using elementary operations. The rows (columns) that at the end remain not-all-zeros will give you both the dimension of the span of the original set but also which original vectors are lin. independent and which ones you can throw away and replace them by new ones that'll be lin. independent with the former, original lin. ind. ones.

And +1 for that use of the verb "prune" ...:)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still don't really understand how that forms a basis.

Comment: Did you do what I proposed? Did you already spot what vectors, out of the original ones, are linearly independent?

Comment: I thought that the linearly independent vectors would be the vectors that make up Y after pruning?

Comment: Yes, the ones that do not become all-zero after reducingthe matrix.